# What does the blind effect do in Diablo 3?

Tags: diablo-iii

I've been playing a monk and I have him half way through Nightmare, however I'm still a little confused about what exactly blinding does to an enemy. Some enemies seem to wander around aimlessly while blinded while some still keep attacking me. What does this status effect actually do?

Comment: I would imagine that the basic effect is to reduce accuracy. There is a rune which confuses enemies also.

Comment: @DavidYell: I've seen at least one source confirming that, but why would a simple reduction in accuracy cause disorientation and interrupted casting? These are two effects that I've noticed in my own playing, so I'm looking for a somewhat authoritative answer.

Comment: Yeah, I would too. Perhaps the blindness blinds them so much that they can't see you so you shed some aggro?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Blind is a Control Impairing Effect in Diablo 3. Blinded enemies have a reduce chance to land hits and will not attack unless they are attacked first. Blind effects usually last a few seconds, depending on the Skill or Ability used.

I don't know how much [this reference](http://www.diablo3skills.net/2012/01/blind.html) is reliable, but it agrees with your (and mine) observation.

Also, notice that elite monsters subjected to [Blinding Flash](http://eu.battle.net/d3/en/class/monk/active/blinding-flash) recover quickly even if they

> suffer a 30% chance to miss with attacks.

What I infer is that, elite monster can target you again in less than Blinding Flash's 3-second duration (even if you don't attack them), but the miss chance stays on for the entire skill duration.

Comment: I just tested Blinding Flash with an eye for watching for this exactly, and this seems to be exactly correct.

Comment: From my testing, it seems as if Blinding bosses doesn't do anything other than the 30% chance to miss. Some elites even seem to work this way, rather than the implied shorter duration disoriented